# How do I iterate jsoup tags, but leave out the first two findings?

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

This is what I want to get date from:

```
<div class='col5'>
<strong><a href="/stellenangebote/107278-supporter-sap-crm?page=1&amp;query%5Bcity%5D=&amp;query%5Bradius%5D=100&amp;query%5Btext%5D=SOA+SAP" title="Supporter SAP CRM (m/w)">Supporter SAP CRM (m/w)</a></strong>
<br>
<a class="job-offer-teaser-company" href="/unternehmen/vesterling-consulting-gmbh" title="Vesterling Consulting GmbH">Vesterling Consulting GmbH</a>
</div>
<div class='col2'>
bundesweit
</div>
<div class='col2'>
12.02.2014
</div>
```

the problem is, that there are two more col5 containers on top, which i want to skip when running this code:

```
Document document = Jsoup.parse(new File("C:/Talend/workspace/WEBCRAWLER/output/absolventa_keywords_"+row[i].trim()+".txt"), "utf-8");
                    Elements elements = document.select(".col5");
                    for (Element element : elements) 
                    {           
                        // Parse Data into Elements
                        Elements jobTitleElement = element.select("a");
                        Elements companyNameElement = element.select("a.job-offer-teaser-company");
                        // problem: Location and Date Both in class "col2".
                        Elements col2Elements = document.select("div.col2"); //This will return a collection of Element objects

                        // Get them in element form and split it with get(0,1)
                        String location = col2Elements.get(4).text(); //Get the first
                        String date = col2Elements.get(5).text(); //Get the second

                        // format date
                        Date timeAdded = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy").parse(date);

                        // Strip Data from unnecessary tags
                        String companyName = companyNameElement.text();
                        String jobTitle = jobTitleElement.text();
                        System.out.println(companyName+ jobTitle + location + timeAdded);
```

How can I skip these elements while iterating through the others?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to skip 2 first elements then how about using

```
for (int i = 2; i<elements.size(); i++) 
{           
    Element element = elements.get(i);
```

instead of

```
for (Element element : elements) 
{
```

Also you shouldn't invoke

```
Elements col2Elements = document.select("div.col2");//This will return a collection of Element objects
```

in a loop since you are getting always same results. Same about

```
String location = col2Elements.get(0).text(); //Get the first
String date = col2Elements.get(1).text(); //Get the second
```

Just invoke it once before loop.